# How to bind two Views side by side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I been following this [Walkthrough](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Entity-Framework-MVVM-Walk-959bb749) which does a great job of explaining switching between two views, plus more.

What I'm trying to adapt the project to do is, instead of switching between two views, is show two views side by side.

Andy set up the following in his MainWindowViewModel placing ViewModels into an OC:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyUIBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewVM> Views {get;set;}

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ViewVM> views = new ObservableCollection<ViewVM>
        {
            new ViewVM{ ViewDisplay="Customers", ViewType = typeof(CustomersView), ViewModelType = typeof(CustomersViewModel)},
            new ViewVM{ ViewDisplay="Products", ViewType = typeof(ProductsView), ViewModelType = typeof(ProductsViewModel)}
        };
        Views = views;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Views");
        views[0].NavigateExecute();
    }
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs navigation calls ShowUserControl() to set the view

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Apply default form level font style
        Style = (Style)FindResource(typeof(Window));
        Messenger.Default.Register<NavigateMessage>(this, (action) => ShowUserControl(action));
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }

    private void ShowUserControl(NavigateMessage nm)
    {
        EditFrame.Content = nm.View;
    }
}
```

**My Code:**

I won't be needing them in an OC and I won't be switching between views, they will be displayed at the same time side-by-side. So I was thinking what I need to do is

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyUIBase
{
    private ViewVM m_MobileDeviceRequestsVM;
    private ViewVM m_AuthorizedMobileDevicesVM;

    public ViewVM MobileDeviceRequestsVM
    {
        get { return m_MobileDeviceRequestsVM; }
    }

    public ViewVM AuthorizedMobileDevicesVM
    {
        get { return m_AuthorizedMobileDevicesVM; }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        m_MobileDeviceRequestsVM = new ViewVM { ViewDisplay = "MobileDeviceRequests", ViewType = typeof(MobileDeviceRequestsView), ViewModelType = typeof(MobileDeviceRequestsViewModel) };
        m_AuthorizedMobileDevicesVM = new ViewVM { ViewDisplay = "AuthorizedMobileDevices", ViewType = typeof(AuthorizedMobileDevicesView), ViewModelType = typeof(AuthorizedMobileDevicesViewModel) };
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is how to bind these ViewModel Views in to my grid, tried using a couple of ContentControl however that's not working.
How can I accomplish this?

```
<Window x:Class="MobileDeviceAuthenticator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MobileDeviceAuthenticator"
        Title="Device Authorization" Height="381" Width="879">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,25,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Authorized Devices" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding AuthorizedMobileDevicesVM.View}" />

            <Label Content="Device Requests" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding MobileDeviceRequestsVM.View}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It looks like the example you linked uses ViewVM's to facilitate the use of "NavigateMessage"s to control which view to show. Since you're not switching views, is there a reason why you still need ViewVM? Even though the author says it's an MVVM approach, storing a usercontrol with a viewmodel class is very NOT MVVM. Not that I'm a MVVM purist by any means, I just feel like using that mechanism complicates the solution to your problem. Also, if your AuthorizedMobileDevicesVM.View is indeed a usercontrol of some sort - it SHOULD work. Have you verified that there are no binding errors?

Comment: potentially helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUwk2-_tRzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the example's ViewVM class again after I made my comment regarding my reservations about the approach. Ignoring any of that and assuming you have not modified the example's ViewVM code below:

```
 public class ViewVM
    {
        public string ViewDisplay { get; set; }
        public Type ViewType { get; set; }
        public Type ViewModelType { get; set; }
        public UserControl View { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand Navigate { get; set; }
        public ViewVM()
        {
            Navigate = new RelayCommand(NavigateExecute);
        }
        public void NavigateExecute()
        {
            if(View == null && ViewType != null)
            {
                View = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(ViewType);
            }
            var msg = new NavigateMessage { View = View, ViewModelType = ViewModelType, ViewType = ViewType };
            Messenger.Default.Send<NavigateMessage>(msg);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the `View` property is only assigned to via reflection when NavigateExecute is called. When you bind to `AuthorizedMobileDevicesVM.View`, it's not instantiated yet. You can move the reflection code into the constructor for your case and it'll work. Of course this means it'll increase memory usage of your application if you're using ViewVM elsewhere for page navigation - looks like it's by design meant to create the view only as necessary.

Comment: That all make sense and thanks for noting your reservations. I have moved away from using ViewVM for this particular window as I agree it is not necessary in this case. You have also given a reason and solution, which I wasn't yet aware of. Appreciate your time!